# regex negative lookahead assertion doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

Why does my pattern produce this result? I expect it to find `ATG` then a sequence of 3 which does not include `TAA`.

```
In [102]: s = 'GATGCCTAAG'
In [103]: pat = re.compile("(ATG((\w\w\w)*)(?!TAA))")
In [104]: pat.findall(s)
Out[104]: [('ATGCCTAAG', 'CCTAAG', 'AAG')]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `findall` method returns a list of matches.  If the pattern contains capturing groups, then each match is a tuple of the strings matched by each capturing group in the pattern.

From [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

> Return all non-overlapping matches of `pattern` in `string`, as a list of strings. The `string` is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result unless they touch the beginning of another match.

Your pattern contains three capturing groups.  The groups are nested.  The first (and outermost) group is the entire pattern, `(ATG((\w\w\w)*)(?!TAA))`.  The second group is `((\w\w\w)*)`.  The third group is `(\w\w\w)`.

Note that the negative lookahead assertion, `(?!TAA)`, is **not** a capturing group.

In essence, your pattern says to match the codon `ATG`, followed by as many codons as possible, but back up two codons if the match would stop at a `TAA` codon.  Since `*` is greedy, your pattern will match a `TAA` codon in the middle.  It will only reject a `TAA` codon (and the codon before that) if the `TAA` occurs at the end of the input string.

Because of your capturing groups, your pattern says that each returned match should contain three strings: the entire sequence of matched codons, the sequence of matched codons excluding the initial `ATG`, and the last matched codon in the sequence.

You can mark a group as non-capturing using `(?:...)`, like this:

```
In [5]: pat = re.compile("(?:ATG(?:(?:\w\w\w)*)(?!TAA))")
```

If your pattern contains no capturing groups, then `findall` returns each match as a single string, instead of as a tuple.

```
In [6]: pat.findall(s)
Out[6]: ['ATGCCTAAG']
```

If you want to stop at the **first** `TAA`, but go to the end of the string if there is no `TAA` at all, you need to check each codon, by putting your negative lookahead assertion inside the repetition:

```
pat = re.compile("ATG(?:(?!TAA)\w\w\w)*")
```

This asserts, at each codon after the initial `ATG`, that it should not match a `TAA` codon.

If you want to stop at the first `TAA` codon, even if that codon is not aligned with the `ATG`, you can do it like this:

```
In [7]: pat = re.compile("ATG(?:(?!.{0,2}TAA)\w\w\w)*")

In [8]: pat.findall(s)
Out[8]: ['ATG']

In [10]: pat.findall('ATGCCTGAATATAAG')
Out[10]: ['ATGCCTGAA']
```

Comment: how to force search only for the entire pattern, but not subpatterns?

Comment: (?!TAA) should not include TAA, but in the final result it is included, why?

Comment: Because `TAA` is not an aligned codon in your input string.  It does not begin on a three-base boundary.  Your pattern only matches codons that are aligned on three-base boundaries.

Comment: I have updated my answer to address matching a non-aligned `TAA`.

Comment: I tried your pattern on three aligned string and it still returns TAA

Comment: I have tested the last pattern in my answer (`In[7]`) and it doesn't return `TAA`, aligned or not.

Comment: Yes, the last pattern does not return, but I need allgned, It looks for me that the fist pattern should not return Alligned TAA, but it does, try it!

Answer (score 0):

Also, in the re module, * includes possibly zero of that item, in addition to what @rob mayoff wrote.

From the docs:

```
*
```

> Causes the resulting RE to match 0 or more repetitions of the
>   preceding RE, as many repetitions as are possible. ab* will match ‘a’,
>   ‘ab’, or ‘a’ followed by any number of ‘b’s.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your best solution would be to make a very simple regular expression that does capture TAA, and then apply a filter that strips out TAA patterns.